# Struggling with function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So I have this assignment to make a turtle draw a polygon using a function: `draw_poly(t, n, sz)`
Where `t` = turtle name, `n` = amount of angles and `sz` = size of each side. I have come up with the following solution:

```py
import turtle

def draw_poly(t, n, sz):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    angle = 360/n
    for _ in range(n):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(angle)

window = turtle.Screen()

draw_poly(tess, 8, 50)

window.mainloop()
```

When I run this I get a name error: 'name 'tess' is not defined'. I thought that because in the function tess is in the spot of the paramater `t` it will use `t = turtle.Turtle()` in the function but this doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an instance of `turtle.Turtle()` and to pass the instance to `draw_poly`. e.g:

```py
import turtle

def draw_poly(t, n, sz):
    angle = 360/n
    for _ in range(n):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(angle)

window = turtle.Screen()
tess = turtle.Turtle()
draw_poly(tess, 8, 50)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working. However, what if you want to do `draw_poly(alex, 8, 50)`, do you need to also write `alex = turtle.Turtle()` or is there any way to do this automatically, like that you can insert any name for the turtle.

Comment: @LST-2020 `alex` is a new instance of  `turtle.Turtle()`, so you have to construct alex `alex = turtle.Turtle()`. Anyway you can use `tess` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

As your function currently stands, it doesn't matter at all what you pass as the first argument, because with `t = turtle.Turtle()` you immediately overwrite whatever has been passed to `t`. If you want to pass an arbitrary name that you can use within the function, you can do that by passing it as a string (put quotemarks around it). But this should still be distinguished from the turtle instance, for example:

```py
import turtle

def draw_poly(t, n, sz):
    turtle.title('This window is for ' + t + '.')
    t_instance = turtle.Turtle()
    angle = 360/n
    for _ in range(n):
        t_instance.forward(sz)
        t_instance.left(angle)

window = turtle.Screen()

draw_poly('tess', 8, 50)

window.mainloop()
```

Or you could let the turtle live outside of the function:

```py
import turtle

def draw_poly(t, n, sz):
    angle = 360/n
    for _ in range(n):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(angle)

window = turtle.Screen()

tess = turtle.Turtle()
draw_poly(tess, 8, 50)

window.mainloop()
```